# Getting saved 0 shards error when sending espresso test suite class to firebase

Tags: ui-automation, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab, test-suite

when I send my test classes one by one to firebase with the same method, I don't get an error, but when I export test suite to target, i am getting this error "There are no Android tests to run.". Could it be a problem caused by annotations? I'll be glad if you can help me.

Here is my test suite class :

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.Suite

@RunWith(Suite::class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(
    SampleScreenTest::class,
    ExampleScreenTest::class,
    SampleListScreenTest::class
)
class TestSuite
```

This is how I added it to Gradle:

```
  perfTests {
            devices.set([
                    [ "model": "NexusLowRes", "version": "23" ]
            ])
            testTargets.set([
             "class com.sample.utils.TestSuite"
            ])
        }
```

This is how I triggered in terminal

```
./gradlew runFlankperfTests
```

Comment: I use fladle plugin and unfortunately is having the same issue with Test Suites. Did you solve your issue by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately, my problem in the test suite continues. I was able to run my tests by giving the package name.